# Assign a Textbox Value to the modal-box on the same page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

How to get the textbox value on code-behind after the textbox value assigned on a modal-box?

This is how the modal-box appear on the page:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Modal Box">
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True">   
    <asp:Button ID="Save_Button" runat="server" Text="Save"></asp:Button>        
</div>
```

In order to assign the value on `Textbox1`, I attach a Javascript function to the LinkButton on a Gridview (the code not showed here) through code-behind based on the LinkButton clicked:

```
Dim myLinkButton As LinkButton    
For i As Integer = 0 To GV1.Rows.Count - 1
  myLinkButton = DirectCast(GV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).FindControl("LinkButton"), LinkButton)
  myLinkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "shopModalPopup('" + .Rows(i).Cells(0).Text & "'); return false;")
Next
```

`Rows(i).Cells(0)` is the first column on the Gridview, it is "`ID`". This `ID` will be assigned to the `Textbox1` while the Linkbutton clicked.

The Javascript code is on the same page as the Gridview code:

```
<script>
var grid_modal_options = {
                    height: 450,
                    width: 550,
                    modal: true
                };

function shopModalPopup(id) {
                    var DataField = id;
                    grid_modal_options.open = function () {
                        $('#dialog-form #Textbox1').val(DataField);
                    };

                    $("#dialog-form").dialog(grid_modal_options);
                    $("#dialog-form").parent().appendTo('form:first');
                }
</script>
```

When I clicked the Save Button on the modal-box, the value on the `Textbox1` can't catch on the code-behind. It always return null value. How to do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: why are you using  <input type="text" id="Textbox1" /> istead of using asp textbox

Comment: @COLDTOLD: Sorry, I've edited the code above. I am using asp:textbox but is still can't get the value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37090/JQuery-UI-Dialog-with-ASP-NET-empty-post-values

i think it might help you the problem might be that the div of dialog is moved outside the form you can solve it by using reference above or just defining another hidden input and update the hidden input with the same value

```
 $('#dialog-form #Textbox1').val(DataField);
 $('hiddenfield').val(DataField);
```

and then read the value from the hidden field

not sure if it the best answer but might work as a quick fix

Answer (score 0):

Does it work without `Readonly="true"`? If so, in your `<asp:textbox>`, replace `Readonly="true"` with `Enabled="false"`.

I haven't tested this, but i recalled `Readonly` causing me issues like this in the past.