# Check a Checkbox using Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

how to make a checkbox checked/unchecked based on the value sent to the Javascript function? Pls [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160185/the-button-didnt-get-fired-while-clicked-on-the-modal-box/10267848#comment13205122_10267848) how to call the **showModalPopup** function.

---

I have a gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS1" >
  <Columns>

    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID"/>

    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit_LinkButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" >
          <asp:Image ID="Edit_Linkbutton_Image" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/edit.png"></asp:Image>
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" Visible="False">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And then I attach a Javascript function to the LinkButton through code-behind:

```
Dim myLinkButton As LinkButton

For i As Integer = 0 To GV1.Rows.Count - 1
  Dim CheckBox1 As String = TryCast(GV1.Rows(i).FindControl("Status"), Label).Text

  myLinkButton = DirectCast(GV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).FindControl("Edit_LinkButton"), LinkButton)
  myLinkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "shopModalPopup('" & .Rows(i).Cells(0).Text & "', '" & CheckBox1 & "'); return false;")
Next
```

`Rows(i).Cells(0)` is the first column on the Gridview, it is "`ID`".

Then, the Javascript function to call the modal-box is:

```
<script>
                var grid_modal_options = {
                    height: 450,
                    width: 550,
                    modal: true
                };

                function shopModalPopup(Field1, Check1) {
                    var DataField1 = Field1; //--> ID
                    var CheckField1 = Check1; //--> Status

                    grid_modal_options.open = function () {
                        $('#dialog-form #Textbox1').val(DataField1);
                        $('#dialog-form #Checkbox1').checked = CheckField1;
                    };

                    $("#dialog-form").dialog(grid_modal_options);
                    $("#dialog-form").parent().appendTo('form:first');
                }
</script>
```

And the code for display the modal-box:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Modal-box" style="display: none;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Text="" Enabled="false">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

The code above doesn't check the checkbox but for the textbox value assigned succesfully. I need the checkbox one is also assigned by the javascript. How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `shopModalPopup`.

Comment: You should read the API docs. Once your code is working correctly, toss it over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com since it could use quite a few stylistic improvements.

Comment: And if you're using unique ids to reference your DOM elements, you don't need to make them any more specific than just the ID

Comment: Pls have a check on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291047/assign-a-textbox-value-to-the-modal-box-on-the-same-page/ . I just don't want to make it redundant to rewrite the same code here. Sorry for missing to enclose the link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.prop()` command:

```
$("#dialog-form #Checkbox1").prop("checked", CheckField1);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I think it should be right but it doesn't work. Am I missing something? Pls see the link provided above to know how to call the function on the Javascript. Thanks :)

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 - what does CheckField1 return?  alert(CheckField1), this should return true in order to set the checkbox value property.

Comment: The CheckField1 return the true/false value. I checked it and return the right value, but still can't check/uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 try:   $("#Checkbox1").prop("checked", CheckField1);
If that doesn't work try: alert($("#dialog-form #Checkbox1")); and see if that returns the object.

Comment: I tried and it returns the object. But still can't set the check/uncheck on the checkbox...

Comment: I've tried using `$("#Checkbox1").prop({checked: true});` but caused every time I am opening the modal-box, it always refresh the page..

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it should be like this:

```
$('#dialog-form #Checkbox1').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Pls see the link provided above to make clear how to call the function on the Javascript. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), with the value of the checkbox as a single-item array to check a checkbox:

```
$('#dialog-form #Checkbox1').val([ "Checkbox1" ]);
```

Make sure the checkbox specifices "Checkbox1" as its `value`.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't work. Pls see the link provided above to make clear how to call the function on the Javascript. :)

Comment: @Does you checkbox have a `value` attribute?

Comment: No, it doesn't... Or I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for being too terse. What I meant was, you need to add a `value` attribute to your checkbox for `val` to work. This is not the most concise way to check a checkbox, but I like it because it uses `val`, similar to other field types.

Comment: You means: `<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" text="" runat="server"/>` ?

Comment: I don't know about ASP markup, but probably something like: `<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" value="Checkbox1" ...`

Comment: Yes, so it should be `text` attribute. I tried it but resulting the same thing.. ><

Comment: Doesn't `text` set the label?